# How to add a button (Rate my App on App Store) before publishing in App Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I'm trying to add a button to make the user rate my app in the app store for iOS 10.3 and earlier versions and i haven't upload my app to the App Store yet so i don't have a link or ID

can any one help me ?
by the way i have this code :

```
@IBAction func rateAppButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions

    }
}
```

Comment: You can create your app in iTunes Connect before you are ready to submit the app for review. Then you will have the needed id to finish your app.

Comment: FYI - requesting app reviews is annoying to users. Reconsider doing this.

Comment: I just added a button, not automatically shown so if the user would rate it will be his choice - Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto your itunesconnect account -> My Apps -> Click on "+" Button ->New iOS App -> Fill require details -> After filling all details goto your App -> Click on More Button -> View on AppStore -> it will redirect you to your App URL this will be universal & will be same after your app goes live